# Angular 10: FormArray se repiten el mismo campo cuando agrego nuevos elementos

Tags: angular, typescript

estoy haciendo un formulario dinamico con productos y con un botón quiero agregar otro form para otro nuevo producto. Para ello estoy utilizando FormArray pero estoy teniendo problemas cuando agrego un nuevo formGroup al arreglo.

Mi component es el siguiente:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormArray, FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-client',
  templateUrl: './client.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./client.component.css'],
  host: {
    class: 'client-app'
  }
})
export class ClientComponent implements OnInit {

  test: FormArray;

  childTest: FormGroup;

  constructor() { 
    this.childTest = new FormGroup({
      inputRandom: new FormControl('')
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
    this.test = new FormArray([]);

    this.test.push(this.childTest);
  }

  public addProduct() {
    const testChild2 = new FormGroup({
      inputRandom: new FormControl('')
    });
    console.log(testChild2.value);
    this.test.push(testChild2);
  }

}
```

Y aqui está mi html:

```
<input class="add-products-button" type="button" value="+" (click)="addProduct()">
<div *ngFor="let item of test.controls; let i=index">
         <div [formGroup]="childTest">
                <input type="text" formControlName="inputRandom">
         </div>
</div>
```

Ahora bien, cuando le doy al botón para agregar me añade otro 'input' sin problema. La cosa es que si previamente lleno un campo y le doy al botón de agregar, entonces el nuevo 'input' que se crea aparece con el mismo contenido que llene previamente, y luego si sigo agregando mas sigue apareciendo lleno.

Aquí una imagen para mostrar a lo que me refiero:
[image: Input repetido]

La verdad no se porque está ocurriendo ya que creo una nueva instancia del FormGroup cuando añado el botón y esta no tiene ningun dato cuando lo imprimo en consola, pero de todas formas cuando lo agrego al arreglo es como si fuera del anterior que cree.

Agradezco enormemente la ayuda que me puedan dar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que esta sucediendo es que estas asignando siempre el mismo `formGroup` en tu template, en esta linea:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of test.controls; let i=index">
    <div [formGroup]="childTest"> <!-- Justo aqui -->
         <input type="text" formControlName="inputRandom">
    </div>
</div>
```

Cuando trabajas con un `formArray`, lo que debes pasar al bloque del formulario son los inputs `formGroupName` con el valor del indice actual, ya que este representa el `formGroup` de cada iteracion. Como le estas diciendo que el formGroup es `childTest`, Angular esta asignando el mismo `FormGroup` en cada iteracion, no el nuevo que creas al agregar un item al formArray.

Intenta cambiar esa declaracion a:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of test.controls; let i=index">
         <div [formGroupName]="i">
                <input type="text" formControlName="inputRandom">
         </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Esto me funcionó sin problemas, Muchas gracias.